# Module over endomorphism ring

Tags: functions, modules

I am trying to solve this problem but it is just confusing me and I don’t know exactly what is going on.

Let $M$ be a left $R$-module. Then $\text{End}_R (M) $, the set of all $R$ -module homomorphisms from $M$ to itself is a ring. We have the map $M \times \text{End}_R (M) \rightarrow M $, $(m, \theta ) \mapsto \theta (m) $. Show that this action makes $M$ into a right $\text{End}_R (M)$-module.

I am just trying to go down all the conditions that make a group into a right module.

I denote $(m , \theta )$ as $m \cdot \theta = \theta (m) $.

I need to show that for all $\theta , \phi \in \text{End}(M)$ and all $m \in M$ that $(m \cdot \theta ) \cdot \phi = m \cdot (\theta \phi )$.

**But** $(m \cdot \theta )\cdot \phi = \phi (m \cdot \theta )=\phi ( \theta (m))= (\phi \theta )(m)= m \cdot ( \phi \theta ).$

Somehow the $\phi $ and $\theta $ have been reversed so I don’t really get what’s happening here.

Answer (score 0):

The statement that you’re trying to prove is wrong.
Instead, $M$ becomes a left $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$-module via
$$
  θ ⋅ m ≔ θ(m)
  \qquad
  \text{for all $θ ∈ \mathrm{End}_R(M)$, $m ∈ M$.}
$$

Comment: Some people define the ring structure of the endomorphism ring of a left module using the *opposite* of composition (Anderson and Fuller do this in their book, for example). The OP did not give any hint as to what his conventions are, so it is really impossible to know if the claim is right or wrong.

Comment: He may not know, actually. I've picked Anderson-Fuller many times, read something, and got things wrong because of that convention of them...

Comment: Can you provide an insight into wha you mean as I think this may be where the confusion lies